# How to insert meshcat in google slides?

Tags: drake

Is any methods can let me insert meshcat in google slides? I see Prof.Russ can insert meshcat in his slides. It's very cool!

I try to find some add-on to do that. However, it doesn't works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what Russ does, but FYI there is a function [pydrake.geometry.Meshcat.StaticHtml](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.geometry.html#pydrake.geometry.Meshcat.StaticHtml) to output an HTML page of the visualization (including a saved animation).

I don't think you can paste an HTML page into Google Slides though, so it wouldn't immediately solve your problem.

Comment: I do use the StaticHtml method, but I don't use Google slides.  I switched to slides.com, primarily so that I could embed more rich content like this.  (I still host the html on my website, and then just insert it into the slide as a iframe).